# AJAX/ Javascript - Pass contents of txt file into Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, text-files

I'm trying to read a list of words from a txt file into a Javascript variable to use later in my script. However, I am unable to pass the variable out of the onreadystatechange function. Is there some simple step that I'm missing?

Source:

```
var xmlhttp;
var list = new Array();
var word;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        list = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
        document.getElementById("testfield").innerHTML = list[0]; //This works
        word = list[0];
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","wordlist.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();

document.getElementById("testfield").innerHTML = word; //This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this code

```
document.getElementById("testfield").innerHTML = word; //This doesn't work
```

is being run **before** your xhr callback.  As a result, word is `undefined`

This `xmlhttp.send();` is sending off your ajax request, and then returning immediately.  Your code then proceeds to

```
document.getElementById("testfield").innerHTML = word;
```

where word is still `undefined`, then, some time later, your ajax request completes, your callback is called, and word is set to the result too late for your to care.